# Finding a Pivotal Quantity

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_1, \dots, X_n$ be i.i.d with probability density function

$$f(x;\theta) = \theta \frac{8^\theta}{x^{\theta +1}}, \qquad x\geq 8,\qquad \theta > 0 $$

And given the statistic $W(X_1, \dots, X_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n ln\left(\frac{X_i}{8}\right)$, I want to find a function $g(\theta)$ s.t:

$$Q(\theta, W) = g(\theta) W \sim \chi^2_k$$

I've tried many things, unfortunately, without any success. Any hints would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all calculate the distribution of $Y_i=log(\frac{X_i}{8})$.

By the fundamental transformation theorem you find

$Y_i \sim Exp(\theta)$ so the rv $W=\sum_y Y \sim Gamma (n;\theta)$

Thus taking $g(\theta)=2\theta$ you get your $\chi_{(k=2n)}^2$

FYK the $f(x,\theta)$  is a known distribution: the Pareto

Comment: Thank you!! Didn't know about Pareto distribution.